# PyTorch DataLoader adding extra dimension for TorchVision MNIST

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I am fairly new to PyTorch and have been experimenting with the DataLoader class.
When I attempt to load the MNIST dataset, the DataLoader appears to add an additional dimension after the batch dimension. I am not sure what is causing this to occur.

```py
import torch
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
from torchvision import transforms

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mnist_train = MNIST(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))
    first_x = mnist_train.data[0]
    print(first_x.shape)  # expect to see [28, 28], actual [28, 28]

    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist_train, batch_size=200)
    batch_x, batch_y = next(iter(train_loader))  # get first batch
    print(batch_x.shape)  # expect to see [200, 28, 28], actual [200, 1, 28, 28]
    # Where is the extra dimension of 1 from?
```

Can anyone shed some light on the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that is the number of channels of the input image. So basically it is

`batch_x.shape = Batch-size, No of channels, Height of the image, Width of the image`

Comment: It looks like you are right. ToTensor inserts the channels dimension first. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor